# Periodic grayscale colormap

Tags: matplotlib

To plot an angle, I need an intuitive periodic colormap. I found the 'hsv' colormap (https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) which is periodic, but very not intuitive because to me green is not further away from blue than from yellow for example.

I think a periodic grayscale colormap is exactly what I need: changing smoothly from black in both edges to white in the middle (or the other way around).

I could not find this colormap in the built-in ones. Does anyone know of such existing colormap or a way to manually define it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to create a the desired black-white-black colormap is to use [`matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

colors = ["black", "white", "black"]
cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", colors)
```

Then use it as any usual colormap:

```
import numpy as np
r = np.linspace(0,1)
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 360)
R,T = np.meshgrid(r,t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="polar"))
ax.pcolormesh(T,R,T, cmap=cmap)

plt.show()
```

[image]